# Best datastructure for a heightmap

Tags: language-agnostic, lua, data-structures

I have a heightmap (a 2D array of floating point values) and I wish to find the highest point on the map, once I have found this point, I want to change its value, and the values of all nearby points. What's the best datastructure to use for efficient retrieval of the highest point?

Requirements:

- Find the highest point efficiently
- Change the value of an arbitrary set of points, this set will always contain the highest current point, and a load of points nearby, the delta will be different for each point.

My current thinking is a priority queue, I can find the highest point in O(1) and I can change a load of values and heapify in O(n log n).

Nb. I've marked this as language-agnostic and Lua, because it is a largely language agnostic question, but I will be implementing the final solution in Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory is not that big of an issue I would store each value in a priority queue as a table so that each table has its data value and references to its closest neighbors. Something like this: { data = number, neighbors = { ... } }.

Comment: hmm, that sounds like an interesting way of doing things. Writing a priority queue in Lua should be fun :D

Comment: It is ;) I recommend first starting out with a list-based version and then moving on to a binary heap-based. The reason for this is that the list-based is a lot faster to implement and thus you know if it was the right path to take.

I recommend overriding the objects' comparison metamethods so that in the priority queue you can compare them with the comparison operators, thus the priority queue can easily be made generic.

Comment: I already had a min-max-heap implemented in C#, so I ported that over, it's blazingly fast :D

Comment: Cool, I hadn't noticed your message earlier :) Did the solution work out as you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

While you are building your priority queue I'd simply be scanning the array and returning the indices of the highest value found.  I can then access any element of the array 'nearby' in O(1).

Or am I missing something ?

Comment: How does scanning the array take O(1)? :/

Comment: I didn't state that scanning the array is O(1).  But, given the indices of an element of an array, the access time is O(1).

Comment: True, but finding the index requires a scan over the entire array, which is what I'm trying to avoid